# jQuery equivalent of PrototypeJs's Hash() class?

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Hash/

trying to find the jQuery equivalent of `new Hash()` that is found in prototypejs for a library conversion.

Any idea where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at jshashtable -

http://code.google.com/p/jshashtable/

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a direct clone, but depending on what you want to do, jQuery has an equivalent (almost maybe?):

E.g.:

```
Proto           jQuery
-----           ------
each            each
toQueryString   param
merge           extend/merge
index           index
get             get
```

and so on...